# Adaptive chained paypal payment :: error 550001

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am working first time with paypal adaptive payment (Chained Payment) and trying to create a demo with sendbox account.

I am using **Angell EYE PayPal PHP Library** for this.

I have changed configration file and set all paypal account details.

Now when I am creating a chained payment with `"ActionType" => "PAY_PRIMARY"`, then it shows success message with below response:

```
Array
(
    [Errors] => Array
        (
        )
    [Ack] => Success
    [Build] => 11853342
    [CorrelationID] => 3c9d6f6c63af1
    [Timestamp] => 2014-07-21T23:16:31.579-07:00
    [PayKey] => AP-xxxxxxxxxx
    [PaymentExecStatus] => CREATED
    [RedirectURL] => https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webscr?cmd=_ap-payment&paykey=AP-6T168633BC6592444
    [XMLRequest] => ReturnAllen_USPAY_PRIMARYhttp://sandbox.domain.com/cancel.phpAPP-80W284485P519543T192.168.3.11USDPRIMARYRECEIVER500.00aus_user1@gd.comtrue50.00aus_user2@gd.comfalse20.00rajvi@origzo.comfalsehttp://sandbox.domain.com/return.php
    [XMLResponse] => 2014-07-21T23:16:31.579-07:00Success3c9d6f6c63af111853342AP-6T168633BC6592444CREATED
)
```

Then I tried to execute `ExecutePayment` API call it gives me response as below:

```
Array
(
    [Errors] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [Receiver] => 
                    [Category] => Application
                    [Domain] => PLATFORM
                    [ErrorID] => 550001
                    [ExceptionID] => 
                    [Message] => This payment request must be authorized by the sender
                    [Parameter] => 
                    [Severity] => Error
                    [Subdomain] => Application
                )

        )

    [Ack] => Failure
    [Build] => 11853342
    [CorrelationID] => b3d52c547fc23
    [Timestamp] => 2014-07-21T23:16:48.190-07:00
    [PaymentExecStatus] => 
    [XMLRequest] => ReturnAllen_USAP-6T168633BC6592444
    [XMLResponse] => 2014-07-21T23:16:48.190-07:00Failureb3d52c547fc2311853342550001PLATFORMApplicationErrorApplicationThis payment request must be authorized by the sender
)
```

I think it gives me some permission error but not getting the exact response and how to solve it. Please guide me on this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you make the initial Pay request you'll see the result is giving you a RedirectURL.  You need to redirect the user to that URL so they can login and agree to complete the payment.

It sounds like you're skipping straight to ExecutePayment without the user ever having been sent over to PayPal to authorize the payment, which is why you're getting that error at that point.

As of now you'll see you can view that URL it's showing for RedirectURL (https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webscr?cmd=_ap-payment&paykey=AP-6T168633BC6592444) and it's loading the PayPal login.  Until that is done with a sandbox buyer account, ExecutePayment will not work.

Also, I'm curious if you really mean to do a delayed chained payment..??  Since you were immediately attempting to run execute payment you may only need a regular chained payment, so you would just use PAY instead of PAY_PRIMARY.  Then you wouldn't need ExecutePayment at all.

Comment: Thanks for your guide. I am have tried as you said and 550001 error gone. But now response shows incomplete. Please check this :: Array
(
    [Errors] => Array
        (
        )

    [Ack] => Success
    [Build] => 11853342
    [CorrelationID] => b95189e596412
    [Timestamp] => 2014-07-22T01:03:37.988-07:00
    [PaymentExecStatus] => INCOMPLETE
    [XMLRequest] => ReturnAllen_USAP-29P945610C482630W
    [XMLResponse] => 2014-07-22T01:03:37.988-07:00Successb95189e59641211853342INCOMPLETE
)

Comment: Ok, now it sounds like you still have PAY_PRIMARY set but you haven't triggered ExecutePayment, so indeed the payment is incomplete.